# Django admin interface multi upload images and relate them to a photoalbum

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-templates

currently I'm trying to get multi upload in my admin interface working.
I'm using the code Luril Garmash provided in his blog: 
http://garmoncheg.blogspot.de/2011/07/django-creating-multi-upload-form.html
He's using the very nice jQuery plugin for multi uploading files from Sebastian Tschan:
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
So do I.

Okay, here's my structure:

models.py:

```
class Photoalbum(models.Model):
    event = models.OneToOneField(Event, help_text="Liste der Events ohne Fotoalbum")
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    facebook = models.BooleanField()

class PhotoalbumImage(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Photoalbum, related_name='images', null=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=storage, editable=False)
    key_data = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I extended the change_form.html template for Photoalbum in order to show the jQuery multi upload form on the add / change site of the Photoalbum model.

Here's the view logic:

views.py:

```
    def multiuploader(request):

    #getting file data for farther manipulations
    file = request.FILES[u'files[]']
    wrapped_file = UploadedFile(file)
    filename = wrapped_file.name
    file_size = wrapped_file.file.size
    log.info ('Got file: "%s"' % str(filename))

    #writing file manually into model
    #because we don't need form of any type.
    image = PhotoalbumImage()
    image.filename=str(filename)
    image.image=file
    image.key_data = image.key_generate
    image.save()
    log.info('File saving done')

    #getting thumbnail url using sorl-thumbnail
    im = get_thumbnail(image, "80x80", quality=50)
    thumb_url = im.url

    #settings imports
    try:
        file_delete_url = settings.MULTI_FILE_DELETE_URL+'/'
        file_url = settings.MULTI_IMAGE_URL+'/'+image.key_data+'/'
    except AttributeError:
        file_delete_url = 'multi_delete/'
        file_url = 'multi_image/'+image.key_data+'/'

    #generating json response array
    result = []
    result.append({"id":image.id,
                   "name":filename, 
                   "size":file_size, 
                   "url":file_url, 
                   "thumbnail_url":thumb_url,
                   "delete_url":file_delete_url+str(image.pk)+'/', 
                   "delete_type":"POST",})
    response_data = json.dumps(result)

    #checking for json data type
    #big thanks to Guy Shapiro
    if "application/json" in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']:
        mimetype = 'application/json'
    else:
        mimetype = 'text/plain'
    return HttpResponse(response_data, mimetype=mimetype)
else: #GET
    return HttpResponse('Only POST accepted')
```

this method is called for each file uploaded by the plugin. 
note: the file upload saves the files to the filesystem and database seperately from the photoalbum, by clicking on "start upload".

Note: my photoalbum add / change template shows the multiuploader for my photoalbumimages on the top with "add files" and "start upload" and on the bottom the form fields for the photoalbum on the bottom with the standard django admin save buttons.
sry that i can't provide a picture because my connection is very, very slow (TOO SLOW) at the place I'm right now.

Thats the point were my problem begins: the files are saved but the photoalbum isn't. I need a save way to save the correct primary key of the photoalbum into each saved file as foreign key. 
My first idea was to handle this problem with the session, save all saved file id's into a list and within the post_save signal for the photoalbum, get those id's and save the correct photoalbum id to those files. But I don't think one should access the session within the model. 
My second idea is to create a temp model, e.g. UploadedPhotos, where I store all the file id's and on post_save signal for the photoalbum, get those id's.

This just doesn't feel right. 
I think the safest way to accomplish my needs would be to upload the files AFTER the photoalbum has been created (after clicking on Save in the Photoalbum model). Then a primary key for the photoalbum would exist and I could save it to each file. 
But I don't have any idea to get this working.

Big thanks for your help in advance. 
Greetings

Comment: Why not just use an inline model admin? You can upload as many images as you want and it will relate your models automatically. You can also make them drag-and-drop orderable with django-admin-sortable, which works with inline models: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-sortable/

Comment: there will be minimum 20 images uploaded for each photoalbum, therefore i need the multiselect
edit: thats why i don't use the built in file form. and i don't know how to combine the custom multi select plugin with the inline functionality

Comment: I don't see how using an inline is any different than what this plugin is supposed to be doing. Uploading 20 images via an ajax call or a regular post is going to take exactly the same amount of time. If you were using an inline, you'd be done by now.

Comment: i need the multiselect functionality. i cant achieve that with the built in file form, right? am i missing something?

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to by "multiselect functionality". Inline model form instances can be dynamically added within the admin interface. So you can create as many PhotoalbumImage form instances as you need. When you come back to edit the parent model, all of your inline instances will also be automatically bound to their forms.

Comment: what i meant with the "multiselect functionality" is the possibility to select multiple files in ONE file selection dialogue. i just want to have one form field for selecting multiple files, not to have multiple form fields for selecting one file each. sorry for not being clear enough

Comment: So how are you going to come back and edit each one of the files in this multi-select upload? How would you allow the user to order them? This seems extremely problematic. Using one field per image makes your life about 1000x easier. How are you going to add properties like `title` or `alt` to these images? Having all of the file field instances in one "field" is making a mole hill into Mount Everest.

Comment: the title of each image is set in the views function multiupload() i posted above. the title will be the actual files name, what is good enough for my purposes. yeah through the multiselect functionality i run into huge problems, but i want to have the comfort of this function (which is, in my opinion, 1000 times better usability)

Comment: In that case, happy coding :) You'll probably need to pass the primary key for the PhotoAlbum in through the querystring and then get the object to associate to each PhotoalbumImage instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i achieved my requirements trough populating a hidden form field with the uploaded and saved id's of the photos in the photoalbum model. this field is a charfield and i put all the id's in it and seperate them with "//" and parse it on the post_save signal of the photoalbum.

Comment: Yea then u have to either make a POST request or remove the if statement where you restrict the request method to be POST